# How to catch error in Observable.forkJoin(...)?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I use `Observable.forkJoin()` to handle the response after both HTTP calls finishes, but if either one of them returns an error, how can I catch that error?

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson) .map((res) => res),
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson) .map((res) => res)
)
.subscribe(res => this.handleResponse(res))
```

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. If one of the calls fails, then the whole observable fails and you can handle it in your subscriber.

Answer (score 63):

You may `catch` the error in each of your observables that are being passed to `forkJoin`:

```ts
// Imports that support chaining of operators in older versions of RxJS
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import {of} from 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import {map} from 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {catch} from 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

// Code with chaining operators in older versions of RxJS
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson).catch(e => Observable.of('Oops!')),
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson).catch(e => Observable.of('Oops!'))
)
.subscribe(res => this.handleResponse(res))
```

Also note that if you use RxJS6, you need to use `catchError` instead of `catch`, and `pipe` operators instead of chaining.

```ts
// Imports in RxJS6
import {forkJoin, of} from 'rxjs';
import {map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

// Code with pipeable operators in RxJS6
forkJoin(
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson).pipe(catchError(e => of('Oops!'))),
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson).pipe(catchError(e => of('Oops!')))
)
  .subscribe(res => this.handleResponse(res))
```

Comment: I got an error saying that `http.post().map().catch()` is not a function

Comment: Did you import catch?

Comment: @matchifang I just can resolve that using pipe tis way  `http.post().pipe(map().catch())`

Comment: Do we really need the `map` here? I mean is it mandatory for the `catchError` or just an example of the `pipe`?

Comment: You shouldn't need a `map`, just a `catchError`

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
forkJoin(
 this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson).pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
 this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson)
)
.subscribe(res => this.handleResponse(res))
```

The second HTTP call will be called normally, even if an error occurs on the first call

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something between these lines?

```
const todo1$ = this.myService.getTodo(1);
const error$ = this.myService.getTodo(201);
const todo2$ = this.myService.getTodo(2);
forkJoin([todo1$, error$, todo2$])
  .subscribe(
    next => console.log(next),
    error => console.log(error)
  );
```

Keep in mind that If any input observable errors at some point, forkJoin will error as well and all other observables will be immediately unsubscribed.

Comment: Should have mentioned `catchError` to avoid losing all the chain if any error occurs.

Comment: I my case, I wanted to break the chain therefore this does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since `forkJoin` returns an observable, you can use the `pipe` operator on the result along with `catchError`:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody1, postJson).map((res) => res),
  this.http.post<any[]>(URL, jsonBody2, postJson).map((res) => res)
)
.pipe(
  catchError(error => {
    // handle error
    throw error;
  })
)
.subscribe(res => this.handleResponse(res))
```

In this case, the `catchError` callback will be triggered if at least one of the requests failed.